# Create group identifiers for regressions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that contains several identifiers. I want to create one new 'group identifier' for every unique combination of the identifiers - Later on, I want to run regressions using `statsmodels`. That is, say I have

```
  id1 id2 id3 
    A   1 100
    A   1 101
    B   1 100
    B   1 100
```

I want to get

```
  id1 id2 id3 groupid 
    A   1 100       0
    A   1 101       1
    B   1 100       2
    B   1 100       2
```

with `id1`, `id2`, `id3` as the set of identifiers. I know that I can get `unique()` to get the unique groups, but how would I efficiently code the rows into which of the unique groups they belong?

Adjusted @Bernie's answer to accommodate for potential 'NaN's:

```
# get a DataFrame with just the unique "keys"
df2 = df.replace(np.NaN, -1)
g = df2.groupby([u'id1',u'id2',u'id3'])
gdf = pd.DataFrame(g.groups.keys(),columns=df.columns)
gdf = gdf.replace(-1, np.NaN)
# an idea is to re-use the index as the 'group_id'
# the next three commands support that 
gdf.sort([u'id1',u'id2',u'id3'],inplace=True)
gdf.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
gdf['group_id'] = gdf.index

# merge on the three id columns
mdf = df.merge(gdf,how='inner',on=df.columns.tolist())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely there are myriad solutions. This is was what I arrived at...

```
>>> df
  id1  id2  id3
0   A    1  100
1   A    1  101
2   B    1  100
3   B    1  100

# get a DataFrame with just the unique "keys"
g = df.groupby([u'id1',u'id2',u'id3'])
gdf = pd.DataFrame(g.groups.keys(),columns=df.columns)

# an idea is to re-use the index as the 'group_id'
# the next three commands support that 
gdf.sort([u'id1',u'id2',u'id3'],inplace=True)
gdf.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
gdf['group_id'] = gdf.index

# merge on the three id columns
mdf = df.merge(gdf,how='inner',on=df.columns.tolist())
```

Produces:

```
  id1  id2  id3  group_id
0   A    1  100         0
1   A    1  101         1
2   B    1  100         2
3   B    1  100         2
```

Comment: I prefer this answer because I can pass along a list of columns - also, I'd expect it to be more efficient.

Comment: You should replace the first line by the following: 'df2 = df.replace(np.NaN, -1)', 'g = df2.groupby(...)'. 'groupby' does not work well ("as expected here") with 'NaN' and will create a separate group for every 'NaN' value.

Comment: Thanks, @FooBar. I updated the answer. Does dropping the NaNs make sense for your purposes?

Comment: I updated my question to show you what I meant. That way, I don't lose NaN values.

Comment: Ok, since you included a revised answer in your question I reverted to my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1': ['A','A','B','B'],'id2':[1,1,1,1],'id3':[100,101,100,100]})

def makegroup(x,y,z):
    return str(x) + str(y) + str(z)

df['groupid'] = df.apply(lambda row: makegroup(row['id1'], row['id2'], row['id3']), axis=1)

groupiddict = {}
groupincrimenter = 1

for x in df['groupid'].unique():
    groupiddict[x] = groupincrimenter
    groupincrimenter += 1

df['groupidINT'] = df.apply(lambda row: int(groupiddict[row['groupid']]), axis=1)
```

Here is the output:

```
  id1  id2  id3 groupid  groupidINT
0   A    1  100   A1100           1
1   A    1  101   A1101           2
2   B    1  100   B1100           3
3   B    1  100   B1100           3
```